# reading stdin for python TDD

Tags: python, tdd, stdin

I want to learn how to read standard input with Python 2 TDD, but I keep hitting the ZNEC runtime error, and no solve is helping me pass. Here's my latest go at the function and test with input():

```
def parens_balance(line):
    parensonly = ''.join(char for char in line if char == '(' or char == ')')
    parenscount = 0
    for i in parensonly: 
        if i == '(':
            parenscount +=1 
        elif i == ')':
            parenscount +=1
    if parenscount % 2 == 0:
        print('{} {}'.format('Y', parensonly))
    else:
        print('{} {}'.format('N', parensonly))

line = input()
print(parens_balance(line))
```

Test case would be `((1+2) * (3-4))` or `(1+2)*3)+5/8)`

Comment: Do you mean "test driven development" with TDD? If so you should probably test input and algorithm seperatly. What do you mean with ZNEC runtime error? Can you give an [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the error output you are getting?

Comment: I've edited my code above. I thought it was TDD, but perhaps I'm incorrect. My code above is being checked against several testcases in the system. The test cases are being passed to input(), which then get passed to my function, however when I run the above the error reads `Runtime Error - NZEC` The instructions for the last two lines were because it says to "Accept input from standard input"

Comment: thoughts? @syntonym